# Minecraft Reset Spawn

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I recently messed up my world spawnpoint with the command `/setworldspawn`. Now, all my compasses are broken, pointing at that spot. I'd used them in various places to show direction, in accordance to where North is. After using the command, they all point at the new spawn point, which messes things up a lot, especially the ones mounted in item frames.

Is there a command to undo this? Or should I just crumple up the compasses and find another option?

Comment: What do you mean you used compasses "to show...where North is"? Compasses in Minecraft never point north, they point to your spawn point (either the last bed you slept in, or world spawn if you haven't slept in a bed or it was broken).

Answer (score 1):

Although there is not a solution to this, a solution would be using a lodestone at 0, 0, assuming you are in 1.16. Though tedious, you could take ALL your compasses, and use them on the lodestone. Now, all of your compasses will point at the origin. However, every compass that you make must be used on the lodestone. I hope that this helps.

Comment: Because of the world spawn radius, you no longer spawn at **(0,0)** but any point in a radius around it. So placing a lodestone at **(0,0)** would be inaccurate as your spawn point  is were default compasses point to.

Answer (score 0):

## **No Unfortunately Not**

Creating a new world spawn, or a lodestone at (0,0) is not a perfect solution; where you spawn for the first time in a Minecraft world is partially random.

---

### Alternatives

You could:

- reset the world spawn at an ideal point with: `/setworlspawn`.
- create pathways around your world.
- substitute mounted compasses for structures. *(e.g an arrow)*
- use maps set to maximum size.
- use rails or some other system to navigate for you.

---

### I hope this helped